# Why wont this class be applied to the image?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some js code which generates an image-tag like this:

```
main_pic_div.innerHTML ="<img src='"+path_big_image+"?"+Math.random();"' class='shadow'>";
```

But the class wont be applied to it...

Here is what you get when you 'view source' in firefox:

```
    <img src="ad_images/Bilar/441372870_1.jpg?0.6932381395385144"/>
```

The class isn't even there, why?

I have tried with all kinds of quotes!

Thanks

Comment: First things, first - what does http://www.jslint.com/ have to say about your syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be

```
main_pic_div.innerHTML ="<img src='"+path_big_image+"?"+Math.random()+"' class='shadow'>";
```

(You left out the plus sign after `Math.random()`)

Comment: Really?  It makes sense that that error would cause the problem that you were getting, because the part of the string with the class would be interpreted separately from the assignment statement.  I will of course defer to you because you have the code but...are you sure?

Comment: Oh!  My mistake.  See my edit.  I removed the semicolon, too.

Comment: It would be even better to use a timestamp instead of a random number: `Date.parse(new Date())`

Comment: @Mathias Bynens: A timestamp would have a greater chance of collisions than a random number.